# How to run a Java application which uses the test resources instead of the main resources?

Tags: java, maven

I have developed a CRUD application with Spring Boot. In the production environment we run a SQL database. To test the data layer we use [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) as the database. To use H2 as the database when running test, we have specified the following in the `\test\resources\application.yml`:

```
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MSSQLServer
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    platform: h2
    username: sa
    password: sa
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    show-sql: true
```

I would like to build/run a version of the application with uses the maven test scope and uses the test resources instead of the `main` resources. Is this possible without manually copy/pasting? Preferably with maven or a Intellij run configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can add active profiles in your yml/properties config (`spring.profiles.active`)
- You can add `@Profile("test")` to your components
- Or in codes, you can call `SpringApplication.setAdditionalProfiles()` to let your application run with certain profile

Take a look the doc [Springboot profiles.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with profiles.
Create a application-test.yml in the main resources. The execute the Main with the profile "test" and also run the unit tests with that profile